# Can't find object 'city' when using formula

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can you spot my error trying to plot a linear model with interaction between column city and sqft?

str(data) looks like this:
[image: str(data) looks like this]

```r
model <- lm(price ~ sqft * city, data = data)
 
ggplot(data, aes(x = sqft, y = price, color = city)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", **formula = y ~ x * city**, se = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "sqft", y = "price", 
  title = "Linear model with interaction term by city")
```

**I'm getting the error that "city" isn't an object**, I've tried moving things around but haven't been able to find the error. Tried moving it around in formula but I'm stranded reading up on the manual/tutorials.

Before that I was using columns price, sqft and city to show relationship between sqft and price.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = sqft, y = price, color = city)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "sqft", y = "price", 
  title = "Relationship of sqft and price by city")
```

Resulting plot:
[image: Looks like this]

Tried some variations of city not being in the aes window and moving method after formula

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = sqft, y = price)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", **formula = y ~ x * city**, se = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "sqft", y = "price", 
  title = "Linear model with interaction term by city")

ggplot(data, aes(x = sqft, y = price)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(**formula = y ~ x * city**,method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "sqft", y = "price", 
  title = "Linear model with interaction term by city")
```

Comment: `geom_smooth` is meant to run a smoothing function of y on x. To estimate more general models I would suggest to do that outside of ggplot2.

Comment: Omitting the formula altogether - running `geom_smooth(method = "lm")` - whilst keeping your `color = city` argument in functions exactly like a linear model with interactions. It draws a line per categorical city with separate intercepts and slopes. These match the stats of the `lm` call, though don't calculate/return a `city` term or an interaction term.